# Try to localization the tabbar-Item don't can convert to string

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need to localize the name oft tabbar and have this in a enum

```
    import Foundation
    import SwiftUI

    enum TabBarItem: Hashable {
        case home, favorites, profile, messeges, impress
        
        var iconName: String {
            switch self {
            case .home: return "house"
            case .favorites: return "heart"
            case .profile: return "person"
            case .messeges: return "message"
            case .impress: return "gear"
            }
        }
        
        var title: String {
            switch self {
            case .home: return "Home"
            case .favorites: return "Favorite"
            case .profile: return "Profile"
            case .messeges: return "Messages"
            case .impress: return localizedString(value: "ImpressTabTitle")
            }
        }
        
        var color: Color {
            switch self {
            case .home: return Color.red
            case .favorites: return Color.blue
            case .profile: return Color.green
            case .messeges: return Color.orange
            case .impress: return Color.purple
            }
        }
        
        func localizedString(value: String) -> String {
            let returnvalue: String = LocalizedStringKey("ImpressTabTitle")
            return returnvalue
        }
     }
```

But I get always the error:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'Text' to return type 'String'
```

Where is my missunderstanding of this?

The string in the localizationfile works, when i use it direkt in a view

```
"ImpressTabTitle" = "Impress";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question lacks something, because the code you show generates another error: `cannot convert value of type 'LocalizedStringKey' to specified type 'String'`. The error is pretty straightforward – you try to return `LocalizedStringKey`, whereas the method is declared to return `String`.

I suppose you're going to use it in your SwiftUI views, right? If so, you can just change your return to `LocalizedStringKey` and pass it to your SwiftUI views directly, as if it were a string literal:

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum TabBarItem: Hashable {

  case home
  case favorites

  func localizedTitle() -> LocalizedStringKey {
    switch self {
      case .home:
        return LocalizedStringKey("HomeTabTitle")
      case .favorites:
        return LocalizedStringKey("FavoritesTabTitle")
    }
  }

}

// SwiftUI usage example.
Text(TabBarItem.home.localizedTitle())
```